# What type is enum values?

Tags: java, collections, enums

I'm very new to Java and can't seem to understand what value my method is returning. I believe it should be a `List`, but that doesn't seem to be the case. What the method is doing is simply fetching all values from an enum class I got. Here is the code:

```
public static List getRandomSquare() {
  // What should replace "List"?
  Square[] squareTypes = Square.values();
  return squareTypes;
}
```

What should be replacing `List` in this case?

Comment: What is the compiler error message that you get? It probably tells you what the expected and actual types are.

Comment: values() method return an array of enums ie Square[], if u want to return List<Square> it should be Arrays.asList(squareTypes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going by the code you posted above, the return type should be `Square[]`, that is, an array of `Square` objects:

```
public static Square[] getRandomSquare() {
    Square[] squareTypes = Square.values();
    return squareTypes;
}
```

If you wanted to return a list of `Square` objects, then we use `Arrays.asList`:

```
public static List<Square> getRandomSquare() {
    Square[] squareTypes = Square.values();
    return Arrays.asList(squareTypes);
}
```

Comment: However, if this method is supposed to pick a random enum value (like the name suggests), the return type should probably be `Square`  (and the implementation also needs to do something about it). (Wild guess-work on my part, of course)

Comment: @Thilo You're probably right.  I'll wait for the OP to pepper my answer with comments though before I change.